# DataReader yields no rows with WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I have an access 2010 database, DataReader returns rows when I omit the 'WHERE' clause, however I have run the query in Access and it does return the necessary rows with the WHERE clause included. Is there a reason it runs in access but not c#?

```
    con.Open();
    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //dt.Columns.Add("PrimaryDate", typeof(string));
    //dt.Columns.Add("Candidate/Contact", typeof(string));
    //dt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
    //dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
    //dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
    //dt.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
    OleDbCommand getCalenderCommand = con.CreateCommand();
    getCalenderCommand.CommandText = "SELECT April2014.PrimaryDate FROM April2014   ;";//WHERE April2014.PrimaryDate LIKE '*"+01042014+"'
    OleDbDataReader dr = getCalenderCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
       {
         while(dr.Read())
          {
            //dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1), dr.GetString(2),       dr.GetString(3), dr.GetString(4), dr.GetString(5) });
           }
       dr.NextResult();
       }
     dr.Close();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Is your April2014.PrimaryDate field a datetime column with time included in its values?

Comment: Are you open to trying LINQ to SQL? You should be able to craft the LINQ Query to build the objects for you.

Answer (score 0):

use ymd format to compare the date like

```
getCalenderCommand.CommandText = "SELECT April2014.PrimaryDate FROM April2014 WHERE April2014.PrimaryDate LIKE '*"+20140401+"'
```

this comparison is for 01 April 2014